# How to set auth token in React and retrieve in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, frontend, backend

I am new to React and node. I am using React.js and Nodejs. I am doing an Axios POST request where I am sending data and in Node.js, I am creating a JWT token.

Now I want to use this token in auth middleware with the code I have made.

I get data in React.js from Node.js, using `res.data`. I can't save the data in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` as it is not accessible by Node.js and gives error `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

How to save the token so that I can get in Node.js?

Comment: You should store your token on the React frontend, this could be a `Cookie`, `localStorage `or `SessionStorage`, then you can send this token to your Node.js backend and verify your token there. Your request could either contain a bearer authorization header or simply send the token in a data object.

Comment: Can u please explain how to send it from react to node?i am storing in local storage in react but then i cant access it in node

Comment: You could check [this tutorial](https://towardsdev.com/jwt-authentication-with-node-js-and-react-dc41ef0e6136) to get started! :)

Comment: You try to store it on nodejs probably. But you have to save it on reactjs. Because your frontend is reactjs. If you have to use it, you can get on localstorage and send it with api's header.

Comment: Yes halil, I stored in local storage i  sent it to nodejs using header and it worked...Btw thank u for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can send it via the request header or even part of the request url, both of which are accessible in nodejs

Comment: Thank u Yisheng Jiang...I got the solution